# Angular Material grid making three columns width 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to use a simple three-column system on an Angular web app. I just used `<mat-grid-list>` tag with its child elements `<mat-grid-tile>` but I see it just fills like the 30% of the screen.

My code

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" id="page">
  <mat-grid-tile id="left-sidebar">
    <!-- Left Sidebar-->
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile id="main-content" colspan="2">
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <app-post></app-post>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile id="right-sidebar">
    <!-- Right Sidebar-->
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

I need this:

[image]

But insted, I am getting this:

[image]

I have already tried to set the CSS like: `mat-grid-list { width: 100%; }` but I still see the same thing.

Any suggestions to make the `mat-grid-list` work like the first image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `colspan="2"` in the second `mat-grid-tile` then you will get the layout like the first image.

html code is below.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
  <mat-grid-tile id="left-sidebar">
    <!-- Left Sidebar-->

  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile id="main-content" colspan="2">
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <app-post></app-post>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile id="right-sidebar">
    <!-- Right Sidebar-->

  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

For reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afaq4s?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html) code.

Comment: I just marked it as the right answer because I see the background now is red, but its content is still being smaller than the parent tile.